# Sum of Each group with the actual data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have been trying to do this in various ways but couldn't get exact solution so any help would be appreciated

Source:

```
Name    ID   Project   SLA
Ab      1     App      100
bc      2     App       80
cd      3     Bap      200
Ef      4     Vap      30
Fg      5     Vap      70
```

Target :

```
Name    ID   Project   SLA
Ab      1     App      100
bc      2     App       80
Null    Null  App      180
cd      3     Bap      200
Null    Null  Bap      200
Ef      4     Vap      30
Fg      5     Vap      70
Null    Null  Vap      100
```

In SQL

Comment: Trying to do this in SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

```
select Name, ID, Project, SLA
from tab
union all
select null, null, Project, SUM(SLA)
from tab
group by project
order by project, id
```

ANSI/ISO standard SQL, should be portable. (Posting was tagged with several different dbms before...)

Comment: This will sort the null first

Comment: It does? Alright, either add NULLS LAST to the order by item (if supported by MS SQL), or add some order by expression to fix it. Shouldn't be too hard to figure out. E.g. "order by project, id is null, id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
WITH t AS 
   (SELECT NAME, ID, PROJECT, SUM(SLA) AS SUM_SLA, GROUPING_ID(NAME, ID) AS GROUPING_ID
   FROM SLA
   GROUP BY ROLLUP(NAME, ID), PROJECT)
SELECT NAME, ID, PROJECT, SUM_SLA
FROM t
WHERE GROUPING_ID IN (0,3);
```

or even more compact

```
SELECT NAME, ID, PROJECT, SUM(SLA) AS SUM_SAL
FROM SLA
GROUP BY PROJECT, GROUPING SETS((NAME, ID), PROJECT);
```

However, I don't know whether it is supported by SQL-Server